# DeadSystemException in HMSPackageManager

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

I faced DeadSystemException in app on Huawei devices when HMSPackageManager tries to get info about services from Android PackageManager.

Stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadSystemException
   at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.queryIntentServicesAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1192)
   at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.queryIntentServices(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1198)
   at com.huawei.hms.utils.HMSPackageManager.f(HMSPackageManager.java:27)
   at com.huawei.hms.utils.HMSPackageManager.i(HMSPackageManager.java:4)
   at com.huawei.hms.utils.HMSPackageManager.refresh(HMSPackageManager.java:16)
   at com.huawei.hms.utils.HMSPackageManager.getHMSPackageName(HMSPackageManager.java:8)
   at com.huawei.hms.utils.HMSPackageManager.getHmsVersionCode(HMSPackageManager.java:1)
   at com.huawei.hms.utils.HMSPackageManager.isApkUpdateNecessary(HMSPackageManager.java)
   at com.huawei.hms.adapter.AvailableAdapter.isHuaweiMobileServicesAvailable(AvailableAdapter.java:77)
   at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.BaseHmsClient.checkAvailabilityAndConnect(BaseHmsClient.java:134)
   at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.BaseHmsClient.connect(BaseHmsClient.java:1)
   at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.HuaweiApiManager$ConnectionManager.connect(HuaweiApiManager.java:97)
   at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.HuaweiApiManager$ConnectionManager.sendRequest(HuaweiApiManager.java:96)
   at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.HuaweiApiManager.connectAndSendRequest(HuaweiApiManager.java:37)
   at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.HuaweiApiManager.handleMessage(HuaweiApiManager.java:35)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Crash occurs on Android 8/9/10/11, so likely it's not android problem. Crash happens only on Huawei devices. Our app not call HMSPackageManager from any place, so I think it happens in time of HMS Core initialization.
Is anyone has same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huawei support said that problem in Android OS, but they try to fix error in next HMS SDK update in mid of september.